# Как удалить из строки все знаки препинания и символы новой строки?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, символы

Как выглядит регулярка для этого? Про p{Punct} знаю, а вот как добавить к ней другие символы - нет.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(reader.readLine()));
            BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(reader.readLine()));
            String fileContent = "";
    
            while (bfr.ready()) {
                fileContent = fileContent + ((char) bfr.read());
            }
            String fileContentChanged = fileContent.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", ""); /* в регулярке не хватает символов новой строки */
            bfw.write(fileContentChanged);
            reader.close();
            bfr.close();
            bfw.close();
        }
    }
```

P.S. Я понимаю, что можно просто создать новую строку и изменить следующей регуляркой, но это похоже на костыль.

Comment: `"[\\p{Punct}\\s&&[^\\h]]"`?

Comment: `"[\\p{Punct}\r\n]"`?

Comment: "[\\p{Punct}\r\n]" - то, что нужно. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
"[\\p{Punct}\r\n]"
```

или

```
"[\\p{Punct}\\s&&[^\\h]]"
```

`"[\\p{Punct}\r\n]"` найдёт все знаки пунктуации, а также символы CR и LF.

`"[\\p{Punct}\\s&&[^\\h]]"` найдёт все знаки пунктуации, а также любые "вертикальные" пробельные символы (т.е. все пробельные символы, которые находит шаблон `\s`, кроме тех, которые находит `\h`, т.е. "горизонтальные" пробельные символы).